# Get 'this' selector index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following code, i need detect my clicked element index:

```
$('#id1, #id2, #id3').click(function(){ console.log( magicIndex(); ) });
```

When I click `<div id="id1">click</div>` div, I need to get `0` as output, because this selector item index is 0.

When I click `<div id="id2">click</div>`, I must get `1` as output.

Comment: Just write a function which returns the magic index ...

Comment: @Teemu This is exactly is the question, since it's not trivial :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the jQuery function index(). This will return the position of the element, if the HTML structure is correct. I just created a jsfiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/zLs4fo0f/6/

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div id="id1">
    aaaaaa
  </div>
  <div id="id3">
    bbbbbb
  </div>
  <div id="id2">
    cccccc
  </div>
</div>

<div id="result" style="color: red;">

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#id1, #id2, #id3').on('click', function() {
    $('#result').text('Index: ' + $(this).index());
});
```

Comment: No, this is not what OP is asking.

Comment: @dfsq This is exactly what he want. Just check out his question again.

Comment: Are you sure it's what he's asking?  If you click on `bbbbbb` it's going to return `1`, but it's the third item (I.e., `2`) in the selector pattern.  The question is unclear.

Comment: It's the accepted answer, so I'm 100% sure, that this is what he wanted... Otherwise he would comment something, or even accepted the answer below, what's handles the other case.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.  Here I am getting index from div 'id'.

```js
function magicIndex(node){
  return node.attr('id').replace('id','')-1;
}

$('#id1, #id2, #id3').click(function(){ console.log( magicIndex($(this)) ); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">Hi</div>
<div id="id2">Hello</div>
<div id="id3">Bye</div>
```

Instead of 'id' if you add one more attr index in div that will be more specific and meaningful as we can not depend on 'id'. something like this

```js
function magicIndex(node){
  return node.attr('index');
}

$('#id1, #id2, #id3').click(function(){ console.log( magicIndex($(this)) ); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" index='0'>Hi</div>
<div id="id2" index='1'>Hello</div>
<div id="id3" index='2'>Bye</div>
```

Comment: Really? What about this `$('p + #id1, table td:first-child, .popup').click(function()` ?

Comment: As I mention he can add index attr which will be more specific